# Java tTorrent libraries: how to install and use these?

Tags: java, netbeans, download, torrent

Basically I'm making a program which can get all the info from movies by using many APIs. It also downloads a .torrent file from the movie. I'd like to download this inside my program and wanted to use [tTorrent](https://github.com/mpetazzoni/ttorrent). The only problem is: how do I have to use it? In read all the install or readme files and it doesn't say anything for me. I understand how to install a normal library, but this has multiple files in multiple maps etc.

So, first question: Can you please explain easily how I install the library step by step?

Second question: Can you also give me the code how to use it to download with a .torrent file?

Btw: If there is any way on automatically opening the .torrent file with qBittorrent, then that would be the only acceptable alternative for me.

Comment: in stack the idea is you do some efforts get stuck and then tell everyone what u did how u did through code and give error message, not simply asking others to help

Answer (score 0):

1) Install maven, look up how to start a quick "Hello World" project using maven. Once you have a grip on it, add

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.turn</groupId>
  <artifactId>ttorrent</artifactId>
  <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

To your pom.xml

2) From the page you linked:

```
// First, instantiate the Client object.
Client client = new Client(
  // This is the interface the client will listen on (you might need something
  // else than localhost here).
  InetAddress.getLocalHost(),

  // Load the torrent from the torrent file and use the given
  // output directory. Partials downloads are automatically recovered.
  SharedTorrent.fromFile(
    new File("/path/to/your.torrent"),
    new File("/path/to/output/directory")));

// You can optionally set download/upload rate limits
// in kB/second. Setting a limit to 0.0 disables rate
// limits.
client.setMaxDownloadRate(50.0);
client.setMaxUploadRate(50.0);

// At this point, can you either call download() to download the torrent and
// stop immediately after...
client.download();

// Or call client.share(...) with a seed time in seconds:
// client.share(3600);
// Which would seed the torrent for an hour after the download is complete.

// Downloading and seeding is done in background threads.
// To wait for this process to finish, call:
client.waitForCompletion();

// At any time you can call client.stop() to interrupt the download.
```